# How to autofill tableA-fieldA based on tableA-fieldB by getting the data from tableB?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

First, some context: I am used to working with Excel, and I have been using it to create production calculators for my worldbuilding hobby. Due to some recent problems with excessive amounts of data needing calculation, I have finally given in and tried switching it all into Access.

I have been doing some readings on how to use Access, and based on that I decided on the following:

1) I have a temperature table for regions (boreal, temperate...) with specific production levels (1,2...)

2) I have a precipitation table for regions (wet, arid...) with specific production levels (1, 2...)

3) I then have a biome table where I mix the above regions to create my biomes with the following fields:
- Biome.
- Precipitation (dropdown menu from table 2).
- Temperature (dropdown menu from table 1).
- Productivity level (which should be Precipitation Production Level from Table 2 times the Temperature Production Level from Table 1).

QUESTION: How can I have the Productivity Level in table 3 be automatic?

NOTE 1: I don't know VBA and this is my first time working with Access.

NOTE 2: I habe been told to just create table 3 as a form, but I do not think that works with what I want to do. Just in case it may be relevant (and I am not seeing the obvious), I'll next describe my first goal at building this database.

DATA ENTRY FORM: all the tables referenced below are connected by the concatenation of latitude-longitude. I have only built it partially (main form and city subform) successfully.
- main form based on table with 3 fields: latitude, longitude, terrain.
- subform based on table with 3 fields: city name, foundation date, collapse date.
- 3 subforms based on 3 tables, each representing a time period, with 2 fields: biome (biomes change in a given area depending on time periods), and its productivity levels.

After building the world, coordinate by coordinate, I will then go to the next phase - creating tables where I identify plants and animals, plus products derived from them and their levels of productivity. This will then be used to create my world's economy system and a list of characters in different levels of wealth.

I can make this work somewhat easily in Excel (without using VBA), but the amount of data will kill the file before I can use it. I only hope I'll manage to pull it off in Access - but I'll deal with this monster one step at a time. Right now, I am just focusing on the question I posted above. Thank you for any assistance you may be able to give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a database trigger meaning that entering data into `biome` table in the specified columns "triggers" the calculation for your third table. Access does not support triggers but there is a workaround. You use a form and create events to the textboxes of the triggering attributes.

- Create a new form based on your `biome` table. I suggest you get the triggers to work first. Later you can add it to your form with all the subforms. Since you are new to Access you do not want to deal with subforms so soon because they make everything more complicated than it needs to be.
- You rename the textboxes Precipitation, Temperature, ProductivityLevel to something like `txtPrecipitation` `txtTemperature` `txtProdLevel`
- You open the VBA-Editor and try the following code in your new form:

.

```
'Trigger Events
private sub txtTemperature_Change()
call CalculateProductivityLevel()
end sub
private sub txtPrecipitation_Change()
call CalculateProductivityLevel()
end sub
private sub txtTemperature_AfterUpdate()
call CalculateProductivityLevel()
end sub
private sub txtPrecipitation_AfterUpdate()
call CalculateProductivityLevel()
end sub

'Calculation Procedure
private sub CalculateProductivityLevel()
  'Check if both attributes have values. If not do not calculate anything
  if (Len(me.txtTemperature & "") = 0) OR (Len(me.txtPreciperation & "") = 0) Then 
    exit sub
  else
    me.txtProdLevel = me.txtTemperature * me.txtTemperature
end sub
```

Note

- The trigger events will call the calulcation procedure when there are new entries in the two attributes or new entries are saved.
- Make sure to put the code in the new form tab of your VBA-editor
- untested code so there might be some errors

Comment: Thanks, too much work at the office has stopped me from putting this into practice so I still can't say whether there are any problems with the code. In the mean time, I have been told calculated queries might also work. I'll probably try both possibilities and see which is easier to do.